# p2p webcam streaming with flash media server 4

Tags: flash, media, webcam, p2p

I know that is possible to make a p2p webcam stream with Cirrus/Stratus or with Adobe liveCycle, but the first is not for commercial use and the second use an adobe's server.
Is possible to set up a my own server with Flash media server 4 and then create a application to do what i want?
I would to create a webcam stream 1->n using p2p.

I cant find any example or any documentation about that and how work the rtmpf protocol of fms4.

If i was not clear make me any question.

Best regards
Claudio

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. FMS4 can act as a rendez-vous server like Cirrus does.

> P2P/RTMFP support with server-side
>   API, you get the same access to P2P
>   network like Flash Player client, plus
>   you can create a stable point from the
>   server, very useful for distributed
>   objects and databases. Next to that,
>   you don’t need to use Adobe Stratus
>   rendezvous-server and you can start
>   building your own commercial P2P apps.

You will find a lot of examples on FlashRealtime.com